# Image is changing its position on viewing

Tags: image, qt, qt-creator, qml, image-rotation

I have made a cell in qml like below

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Image {
     source: "pics/snake.png"
     smooth: true
      }
```

In another .qml file, I have included it like

```
 Cell {
    id: snake
    x: 301
    y: 30
    width: 30
    height: 67
    rotation: 0
    z: 6
 }
```

When rotation is 0, everything is right but when I **set rotation to some value** then image's position changes on viewing it. The defined x and y values remain same but **position only changes when I view it.** Help me fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually the origin is shifting. In the design window, on the right-bottom, select **Advanced** Tab and select the origin in 3x3 matrix of dots. Change it and then reselect the middle-one. Adjust your image. Now, it will be aligned correctly.

Alternatively you can add
    transformOrigin:Item.Center